# @ManyToMany annotated list of strings? Is it ever possible?

Tags: jpa

I have users and each user has several roles. Roles and users are in many-to-many relationship. But the role is just a name. I've got stuck in this phase:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="users2roles")
private Collection<String> roles;
```

There is missing the name of target table. I was searching on Internet, but nothing have found. I don't wannt to create special entity class to wrap one string value. Is there some another way, isn't?

Is there any way to make it work or makes JPA me create a new entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Collection of Strings isn't **relating** one object to another so cannot be a @OneToMany or @ManyToMany - ought to be @ElementCollection. It's a collection of Strings, nothing more. Yes, it can be stored in a join table, but using @CollectionTable.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I need to create an entity. And can I use `@ManyToOne` for String field?

Comment: No. You mark the field as @ElementCollection/CollectionTable, as said above. Look you use OneToOne,OneToMany,ManyToOne,ManyToMany for *relations*, and a String is not a relation.