# ManyToMany relationship with List of Strings? Is it possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to add List of String Tags to entity object:

```
@ManyToMany
private List<String> tags;
```

Is it possible to do that without creating new entity object Tag {id,tag}?

It is possible to do `OneToMany` relation with using `@ElementCollection` annotation.
But is it possible to create `ManyToMany` relation?
Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@ManyToMany annotated list of strings? Is it ever possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890166/manytomany-annotated-list-of-strings-is-it-ever-possible)

Comment: That is 7 years old topic with no correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible.

@ElementCollection can be used only with OneToMany relation. 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

@ElementCollection can be used with basic type or embeddable class.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html

@ManyToMany can be used only on Entity class.  see [@ManyToMany annotated list of strings? Is it ever possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890166/manytomany-annotated-list-of-strings-is-it-ever-possible)

Solution is to wrap string in an Entity with id.